# Why is 台北 spelled Taipei, not Taibei?

Tags: pinyin, word

I just tried to type in *taipei* in iOS but it didn't return any correct prediction. After my investigation, I found that it is *taibei*, not *taipei*, to get the correct pinyin result.

However, now I wonder why it is called *taipei*. 台 is *tai* like 台风 and 北 is *bei* like 北美洲. So why is it called *taipei*? I think in traditional chiese it should also be typed in as *taibei*...

Comment: You can also see Tsinghua University which is 清华大学（qing1hua2 da4xue2）.

Comment: This begs the question as to why the Wade-Giles version Taipei survives whereas the Wade-Giles spelling Peking has been largely expunged. Is this political?

Comment: @ThomasDoe: Almost all cities in Taiwan are more often seen with Wade-Giles spelling than Pinyin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taipei#Romanization): the spelling "Taipei" derives from the [Wade–Giles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wade%E2%80%93Giles) romanization T'ai-pei. "Taibei" is [pinyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A0ny%C7%94_P%C4%ABny%C4%ABn), which iOS supports as an input method.

Wade-Giles used to be the standard method of romanization so it shows up in a lot of older Chinese names like "Chiang Ching-kuo".

Pinyin has its own disadvantages, especially when spoken by English speakers. Consonants like "zh", "q", or syllables like "ri", "shi" sound very different from what an English speaker might expect.

Comment: It's the same reason that Beijing was spelled as "Peking" (as "peking duck")

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Pinyin was invented by the PRC, and Wade-Giles continued to be used in Taiwan long after China had stopped using it.